# Synchronized HighCharts does not work when charts have different width

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

In HighCharts, I tried with [Synchronized multi charts](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/synchronized-charts) as explained in the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/synchronized-charts/). It works well if provided all charts have equal width.

```
$('#container').bind('mousemove touchmove touchstart', function (e) {
    var chart,
        point,
        i,
        event;

    for (i = 0; i < Highcharts.charts.length; i = i + 1) {
        chart = Highcharts.charts[i];
        event = chart.pointer.normalize(e.originalEvent); // Find coordinates within the chart
        point = chart.series[0].searchPoint(event, true); // Get the hovered point

        if (point) {
            point.highlight(e);
        }
    }
});
```

But If I change the width of the charts to different sizes, then tooltip does not sync properly. You can check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fizerkhan/s8veared/).

Is there any way to sync even if charts have different sizes?

Comment: What you mean by _tooltip doesn't sync properly_

Comment: I assume what he means is, in the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fizerkhan/s8veared/) when I keep the cursor in the last chart at 5km x-axis, the first chart is at 3.8km and the second chart is at 4.2km. They want all of them to be in sync, independent of the size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have data with the same x coordinates you can catch the point from the hovered chart and then find the corresponded points in the other two charts - and call `highlight()`.

```
function highlightPoints(e) {
  const container = this;
  const charts = Highcharts.charts.slice();
  const chartIndex = charts.findIndex(chart => chart.renderTo === container);

  if (chartIndex > -1) {
    const chart = charts.splice(chartIndex, 1)[0];

    const event = chart.pointer.normalize(e.originalEvent); // Find coordinates within the chart
    const point = chart.series[0].searchPoint(event, true); // Get the hovered point

    if (point) {
      const x = point.x;
      point.highlight(e);

      charts.forEach(chart => {
        const points = chart.series[0].points;
        for (let i = 0; i < points.length; i = i + 1) {
          if (points[i].x === x) {
            points[i].highlight(e);
            break;
          }
        }
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Bind the mousemove event

```
  $('.chart-0, .chart-1, .chart-2').on('mousemove', highlightPoints);
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/5vcc6z40/

Comment: It works great. One small issue. When I have one stacked area chart with 3 stacks, I can only access top chart tooltips, not a lower level charts.

Comment: In your initial code, you access only the first series (series[0]) - if you want to access other series, change the index. If you want access all of the series, then you need to change your initial code a little - use a shared tooltip and loop series in the chart - http://jsfiddle.net/5vcc6z40/1/