# HighCharts Synchronized Across Separate Containers/Divs

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'd like to have synchronized crosshairs & tooltips across multiple charts on a single page, as demonstrated by this [official demo](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/synchronized-charts) from Highcharts.

***However***, their demo assumes that all of my charts are in a single `<div id="container">`. **They are not.** They are in multiple containers scattered throughout the page.

[Here is a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x27khmp6/2/) (http://jsfiddle.net/x27khmp6/2/) that has an example of two of my charts with different divs, `<div id="graph1">` and `<div id="graph2">`. On the real page, there are a total of 7 charts.

I'm afraid I can't even begin to process understanding how I'm supposed to apply the [demo](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/synchronized-charts) from Highcharts into my situation. Can anybody point me in the right direction to help me understand how I can get started with this?

Thanks in advance for your kind help.

Comment: If you wrap all charts in shared container that goes outside of your `graph1` and `graph2` divs, then use the code from the offical demo it kinda works: http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/x27khmp6/14/. Not 100% synced, but that is probably due to different amount of points. If you start there and do some troubleshooting, it should be possible to get it working as you want.

Comment: Thank you, ewolden. That's a good start. One thing I'm noticing is that the synchronization seems to be on the physical position of the crosshairs, and not on the underlying data. 

For example, I reduced one graph to `width: 75%;` and the sync seems to follow the physical space and not the data: http://jsfiddle.net/x27khmp6/22/

Also, do you know why the sync works on the top graph but not the bottom? Thank you kindly.

Comment: Assuming that your datasets for all charts are transparent between each other, then you can highlight appropriate point basing on its position.  Here you have related topic, which should be helpful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42529308/synchronized-highcharts-does-not-work-when-charts-have-different-width